# How to get variable from text file into Bash variable

Tags: bash, kill, pid

Simple question, in BASH I'm trying to read in a .pid file to kill a process.  How do I read that file into a variable.  All the examples I have found are trying to read in many lines. I only want to read the one file that just contains the PID

```
#!/bin/sh
PIDFile="/var/run/app_to_kill.pid"
CurPID=(<$PIDFile)

kill -9 $CurPID
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You're almost there:

```
CurPID=$(<"$PIDFile")
```

In the example you gave, you don't even need the temp variable. Just do:

```
kill -9 $(<"$PIDFile")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please remember to accept the answer that best solves your problem, by pressing the [checkmark sign](http://i.imgur.com/uqJeW.png). When you see good Q&A, vote them up by using the [gray triangles](http://i.imgur.com/kygEP.png). Happy New Year!!

Comment: @JaypalSingh if you are replying to a comment and that person is not the person who wrote the answer, you need to prefix their name at the beginning like I did with you.  Otherwise without it, the person who wrote the answer (me) gets notified =)

Comment: Oops sorry about that @SiegeX.

Comment: @JaypalSingh no worries, appreciate the comment

Answer (score 9):

POSIX portable way:

```
$ read pid <$pidfile
```

See: [pid=`cat $pidfile` or read pid <$pidfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21432883/pid-cat-pidfile-or-read-pid-pidfile)